# UICollectionView supplementary view init getting called over and over on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my UICollectionView, I have a supplementary header. Everything works fine at first, then as I use the app, it looks like the init method in my header's cell starts getting called every time I scroll over it, and it becomes laggy. I can tell somethings wrong because the shadow on a view inside my header starts to attach again every time I scroll over it like so [image: shadow getting stacked]

Here is where I setup my header

```
switch kind {

            case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:

                let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "feeds", for: indexPath) as! ChangeFeedCell
                header.feedsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showFeeds), for: .touchUpInside)
                header.typeButtonWhole.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeFeeds), for: .touchUpInside)
                header.topButtonWhole.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeTopSort), for: .touchUpInside)
                
                feedLabelsDelegate = header
                return header

            case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter:
                let footer = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer", for: indexPath) as! LoadingFooterCell
                showLoaderDelegate = footer
                footer.backgroundColor = .clear
                return footer
            default:

                fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
            }
```

Comment: Did you register the header & footer classes with `register(_:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:)`?

Comment: @AdamPro13 yes I did - `collectionView.register(ChangeFeedCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "feeds")`